# Input not updating its dependent input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here are my 4 input fields;

```
//Main Category 
 <select id="category" name="category" required onchange="jsfunction(this)">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Non-Current Asset">Non-Current Asset 11</option>
            <option value="Current Asset">Current Asset 12</option>
 </select><br>

//Sub Code  
  <input id="sub_code" type="number" min="11" max="99" name="sub_code" required placeholder="11 to 99" oninput="account_code.value = parseInt(main_code.value + sub_code.value)"><br>
//Main Code
  <input id="main_code" type="text" name="main_code" readonly placeholder="Do not fill this." oninput="account_code.value = parseInt(main_code.value + sub_code.value)"><br>
// Account Code
   <input id="account_code" type="text" max="2" name="account_code" readonly placeholder="Do not fill this.">
```

When I select "Main Category" input, it updates correctly "Main Code" field.

"Account Code" field is merge of "Sub code" and "Account code".

The problem is that when "Sub code" is already filled and I change "Main Category" input this change is not transferred to "Account code" field.

Here is my Javascript

```
<script>
 function jsfunction(element)
 {
    var mnCode = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
    mnCode = mnCode.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    document.getElementById("main_code").value=mnCode;
 }
</script>
```

Also here is the fiddle where javascript code not work when I write it in JAVASCRIPT box. https://jsfiddle.net/caabdul/8jpdtqs0/

```js
function jsfunction(element)
{
  var mnCode = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
  mnCode = mnCode.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  document.getElementById("main_code").value=mnCode;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Main Category*  <select id="category" name="category" required onchange="jsfunction(this)">
                      <option value=""></option>
                      <option value="Non-Current Asset">Non-Current Asset 11</option>
                      <option value="Current Asset">Current Asset 12</option>
                      </select><br>
Sub Code*       <input id="sub_code" type="number" min="11" max="99" name="sub_code" required placeholder="11 to 99" oninput="account_code.value = parseInt(main_code.value + sub_code.value)"><br>
Main Code       <input id="main_code" type="text" name="main_code" readonly placeholder="Do not fill this." oninput="account_code.value = parseInt(main_code.value + sub_code.value)"><br>
Account Code*   <input id="account_code" type="text" max="2" name="account_code" readonly placeholder="Do not fill this.">
```

Comment: Sorry a mistake in description;
Correct statement is: "Account Code" field is merge of "Sub code" and "Main Code".

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8jpdtqs0/7/

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

1. You need to trigger the `oninput` event manually within the code since it won't trigger when you are changing value programmatically.
2. Parse the string value before addition otherwise, the result would be string concatenation of input values.

```html
Main Category*
<select id="category" name="category" required onchange="jsfunction(this)">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Non-Current Asset">Non-Current Asset 11</option>
  <option value="Current Asset">Current Asset 12</option>
</select>
<br>Sub Code*
<input id="sub_code" type="number" min="11" max="99" name="sub_code" required placeholder="11 to 99" oninput="account_code.value = (Number(main_code.value) + Number(sub_code.value))||0">
<br>Main Code
<input id="main_code" type="text" name="main_code" readonly placeholder="Do not fill this." oninput="account_code.value = (Number(main_code.value) + Number(sub_code.value))||0">
<br>Account Code*
<input id="account_code" type="text" max="2" name="account_code" readonly placeholder="Do not fill this.">
<script>
  function jsfunction(element) {
    var mnCode = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
    var input = document.getElementById("main_code");
    mnCode = mnCode.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    input.value = mnCode;
    input.oninput()
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but still a small issue. When I enter 11 in Sub code and select 11 in main category then Account Code must show "1111", and not sum of 11+11=22.

Answer (score 0):

This cause you are change Account Code input value on main code oninput event you need add code that change value to your `function jsfunction(element)`

```
<script>
function jsfunction(element)
{
    var mnCode = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
    mnCode = mnCode.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    document.getElementById("main_code").value=mnCode;
    account_code.value = parseInt(main_code.value + sub_code.value);
}</script>
```